# Como abrir o site do Twitter dentro de um Iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Estou tentando, abrir o site do Twitter dentro de um *iframe*

```
<iframe src="https://twitter.com/" width="700" height="700" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

ou mostrando um determinado asssunto

```
<iframe src="https://twitter.com/search?q=Agricultura&src=tren" width="700" height="700" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Gostaria de colocar ao lado de uma pagina web o *iframe*, porém ele não mostra nada.
O Twitter tem algum bloqueio para o uso dele em paginas web?
Se for possível alguém poderia me mostrar como se faz?

Answer (score 4):

O Twitter bloqueia isso por uma configuração do próprio servidor deles, enviado uma flag pela Resposta HTTP:

```
X-Frame-Options = "SAMEORIGIN"
```

Assim, carregar páginas do site deles num iframe só será possível dentro do mesmo domínio (twitter.com). O seu navegador irá negar abrir o conteúdo ao identificar esse valor na Resposta HTTP. Como deu para entender, isso é uma configuração de **segurança**, para evitar *hijackings*.

Não há muito o que você possa fazer. Podem até haver "hacks", que se aproveitam de alguma brecha de segurança, por "GET", mesclando o valor no Header em linguagem server-side, plugins no Chrome ou Fiddle. Mas para isso é esperado que seja corrigido em alguma atualização dos navegadores ou servidores-web, e a qualquer hora pode parar de funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

> O Twitter bloqueia isso por uma configuração do próprio servidor deles, enviado uma flag pela Resposta HTTP:

Porém o Twitter disponibiliza uma API que realiza busca veja se ela te ajuda em algo "https://twitter.com/search?q=%40a_sua_busca" *Ela não funciona em Iframe*